# HTML Table Layout, image included with markup for intended outcome

Tags: html

Here is the image of the HTML table design. Please help me out to convert this outline into HTML markup.

NOTE: Unfortunately, this must include a table layout.

[image: See Image]

Here is my markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style=" width: 400px;">
  <tr>
    <th colspan= "3">1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan= "2">2</th>
    <th rowspan= "2">3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan= "3">4</th>
    <th colspan= "1">5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to do this exactly like the image which I've attached above.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Here is my markup. I can't pull off the whole thing together like this image 

https://codeshare.io/2j3gOP

Comment: Please edit the question to include relevant code.  HTML/CSS/JS code can (and should) even be made into a runnable code snippet to demonstrate.  Describe the specific part you're trying to implement and how your attempt isn't working.  As an aside, for this "table" structure you might consider nested tables.  Or, since it's not actually a "table", you might consider styled div elements.

Comment: I did. Could you please help me to get the whole thing using table?

Comment: Attach the image in the question. Avoid external links like the one you've used

Comment: I've already added an image above. Could you please help me out? It would be great help...

Answer (score 2):

### `display: grid`

Using `display: grid`, you use your parent element to set your `width` and `height`, then define your `grid-template-column` and `grid-template-rows` in fractions and layout the children elements using the `grid-template-areas` rule in the parents css.

Then in your child elements, you define their `grid-area` as their class selectors. This is also dynamic because it fills the parents width and height using the unit of measure you choose.

In my example I use `1fr`. So in the case of the *columns*, we have 5 measurements which each take up one fraction => ***1fr***, as it is ***90vw*** in ***width***, this means the 5 sections split the ***90vw*** equally, basically *20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%* of **90vw** gives us the overall width and each child will be ***20%*** width of the parents **90vw**. This works using the same principle for rows.

So using this method we can write the CSS to display a grid 5 fractions wide (*columns*) and 5 fractions high (*rows*) then set our  `grid-template-areas` in the same pattern they will be displayed on the page.

```
  grid-template-areas: 
    "one one one one one" 
    "two two two three three" 
    "four five five three three" 
    "four eight nine three three" 
    "four eight nine six seven";
```

Setting up the children of the display grid in that pattern, again we must define the childrens selectors `grid-area` rule using their selector.

```
.one {
  grid-area: one;
}
```

```css
.cont {
  display: grid;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "one one one one one" 
    "two two two three three" 
    "four five five three three" 
    "four eight nine three three" 
    "four eight nine six seven";
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}

.seven {
  grid-area: seven;
}

.eight {
  grid-area: eight;
}

.nine {
  grid-area: nine;
}

.divs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="one divs">1</div>
    <div class="two divs">2</div>
    <div class="three divs">3</div>
    <div class="four divs">4</div>
    <div class="five divs">5</div>
    <div class="six divs">6</div>
    <div class="seven divs">7</div>
    <div class="eight divs">8</div>
    <div class="nine divs">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Using a Table:

So without setting your height rule for your ***tr's*** you will get a weird layout that does not look like you have five rows.

[image: This has all the proper spans set in the cells]

Once you set your height for your rows, it will parse the table correctly provided you have your ***colspan*** and ***rowspan*** set up properly

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

tr {
 height: 10vh;
 width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<table style=" width: 400px;">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5">1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">2</th>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="3">3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">4</th>
    <th colspan="2">5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td rowspan="2">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a great help man. I know grid and flex so well. But this time I have to do it using table(annoying to me). This is for school homework actually. :D But I can't solve the tiles using the table.

Comment: @NorthernLights I have edited the answer to include a table layout for you.

Comment: It's is amazing. This is my first question or asking here at StackOverflow. You guys are really really life savior. I want to learn more and more useful things from here. Take my gratitude, Mr. Dale.

Comment: @NorthernLights Stackoverflow is a great site, I would suggest getting to know the ropes for posting and asking questions on here. Make sure you are *always* adding reproducible code examples in your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code down below... then to remove the extra boarder around it add this `border-collapse: collapse;`   to your table style:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 100;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table style=" width: 400px;">
      <tr>
        <th colspan= "5">1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan= "3">2</th>
        <th colspan= "2" rowspan= "3">3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan= "3">4</th>
        <th colspan= "2">5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan= "2">8</th>
        <th rowspan= "2">9</th>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <th rowspan= "2">6</th>
        <th rowspan= "2">7</th>
      </tr>
     
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've learned from your snippets. This is a great help man. Please take my gratitude. Hopefully, in the future, I will be able to help others as you guys did me today.